Request for Review: ESP32 Programmer Board Design
I have designed an ESP32 programmer board using Altium Designer and would love to get some feedback from the community.
I am sharing the schematic and PCB layout images below, as well as the .pcb and .sch files for anyone who would like to take a closer look.
Link to PCB project files on google Driver




Here's a summary of the issues identified and addressed so far:

Type-C Interface Design:
Initial feedback indicated that the Type-C interface was not designed correctly.
Solution: Use a Type-A to Type-C cable and ensure correct Type-C interface design by pulling down both CC pins with 5.1k resistors.

USB Compatibility:
Concern that the USB connection would not work on a Type-C port without the correct design.
Solution: Ensuring the CC pins are correctly pulled down for proper functionality.

Input Capacitance:
The initial design had an input capacitance exceeding the USB specification by a factor of 10.
Solution: Reduced the input capacitance to 10μF to comply with the USB standard.



Don't these already exist? The USB won't work on a Type-C port and it will only work on Type-A port with a Type-A to Type-C cable. Also the input capacitance exceeds the allowable value for USB devices by a factor of 10. Same mistakes people ask here over and over again. Have you done a search here for similar questions, this might be closed as a duplicate.

Thank you for your feedback.
I understand your concerns. I opted to use a Type-A to Type-C cable intentionally for my specific application requirements. Regarding the input capacitance, I have revised the design to comply with the USB specification by reducing it to 10μF.
I appreciate your insights and suggestions.

What I meant is that you have designed the Type-C interface incorrectly. If you don't want to design a Type-C interface to work correctly as specifed by standard, why not simply use a MicroUSB or some other connector? Or just fix the Type-C interface to work as expected? It will not work if your laptop only has a Type-C port.

Sure, I understand. So, if I pull down the CC pin with a 5.1k resistor, will that resolve the issue?

There are two CC pins. You need to pull both of them down. Separately.

Thank you for the clarification. I'll ensure to pull down both CC pins separately with 5.1k resistors.
I appreciate your help!
